# Converting JSON data to a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

If I have a list of dict objects, I can do something like this to create my dataframe:

```
my_dict_list = [dict1, dict2, dict3, ...]

cols = ['columnA', 'columnB', 'columnC'] # I choose which keys I want to keep

df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict_list, columns=cols)
```

And it works like a charm.

But in my case, for some specific keys, the dicts values contain some other dicts, and I want to keep some keys of this ones to create my columns dataframes.

I've been trying to find the solution, but I failed

Here is an extract:

[image]

The 3 first entries of my list : https://wetransfer.com/downloads/8ba8d89ec70def6f46e8d6ca01ef553420170902233517/44ad5f

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What is the structure of your dictionaries?  Please provide some samples.

Comment: @ScottBoston It's a list of tweets. Each entry of the list is a dictionnary with some keys like "time", "text", "location" etc. But the key named "user" is a dictionnary with a list of keys like "name", "screen_name", "location" etc.

Comment: @NicoDesh If you could please provide around 2-3 dictionaries in your list as data, we can help. I think I know what you need.

Comment: In text form please...! `print(data)`

Comment: Also, specify exactly what columns you want from "user".

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ from "user", I want "name" and "screen_name"

Comment: And... for the outer keys... what columns do you want retained?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ "created_at" and "text"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`pd.io.json.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html) and a little pre-processing:

```
import pandas as pd

cols = ['created_at', 'text', 'user']
user_cols = ['name', 'screen_name']

data2 = [{k : x[k] for k in cols} for x in data]    
for d in data2:
     d['user'] = {k : d['user'][k] for k in user_cols}

out = pd.io.json.json_normalize(data2)\
          .rename(columns=lambda x: x.replace(r'user.', ''))
print(out)

                       created_at  \
0  Sat Sep 02 07:10:33 +0000 2017   
1  Fri Sep 01 19:58:18 +0000 2017   
2  Fri Sep 01 18:53:27 +0000 2017   

                                                text            name  \
0  @SitePenalise On pourrait rajouter Les EMD son...  Régis Stéphant   
1  Possible de recevoir la dernière version à jou...  Pierrick Butty   
2  Les sites placés en page 1 sur mots clés à for...   Site Pénalisé   

     screen_name  
0      Ledzep_56  
1  pierrickbutty  
2   SitePenalise
```